# Why does `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator` not propagate on container move?

Tags: c++, c++17, allocator

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/polymorphic_allocator:

> `polymorphic_allocator` does not propagate on container copy assignment, move assignment, or swap. As a result, move assignment of a `polymorphic_allocator`-using container can throw, and swapping two `polymorphic_allocator`-using containers whose allocators do not compare equal results in undefined behavior.

Why would I ever want this behavior? Not only does this seem to introduce gratuitous undefined behavior on swap, but more importantly for my purposes, it implies that `std::pmr::vector` is effectively a non-move-assignable type. I mean, it's move-assignable, but that's almost guaranteed to be inefficient.

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int> w;
w = std::move(v);  // nocopy, nothrow

std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource mr(1000);
std::pmr::vector<int> v( {1, 2, 3}, &mr );
std::pmr::vector<int> w;
w = std::move(v);  // yescopy, yesthrow
```

My guess is that this is a primitive attempt to deal with ownership issues. In my second example above, `v` holds a reference to `mr` but `v` does not actually *own* `mr`. Allowing non-owning references to propagate unchecked throughout the system would tend to introduce lots of subtle bugs. So rather than invent an *owning* allocator, the designers decided simply *not to propagate* the reference to `mr`. This ended up having bad effects, such as that move-assigning a vector now copies its data; but you don't end up with quite so many dangling pointers to memory resources. (*Some* yes, but *not as many*.)

---

P.S. I do already see that you can avoid the copying/throwing by setting up the allocator in advance, like this:

```
std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource mr(1000);
std::pmr::vector<int> v( {1, 2, 3}, &mr );
std::pmr::vector<int> w(v.get_allocator());
w = std::move(v);  // nocopy, nothrow
```

Comment: "*that's almost guaranteed to be inefficient*" The standard *never* guaranteed that any container move-assignment operation was constant time. It says so right in the requirements: move assignment is *linear*. Move *construction* is constant time, but not assignment. Generally speaking, people don't move into *existing* containers all that often. As such, it's not a big deal. Furthermore, the move operation will not *copy* the elements. It will simply move them. So it's not the same thing as saying there is no move assignment.

Answer (score 10):

The `allocator_traits<>::propagate_on_container_copy/move_assignment/swap` are *static* properties of an allocator. A polymorphic allocator, by design, has its properties defined at *runtime*. Some polymorphic allocators can propagate to others, and some cannot.

Therefore, it is impossible for these properties to be known at compile time. So the PMR allocator must *assume* the worst case at compile time: no propagation.

Let's take your example, with an alteration:

```
std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource mr(1000);
std::pmr::vector<int> v( {1, 2, 3}, &mr );
std::pmr::vector<int> w;
auto a1 = w.get_allocator();
w = std::move(v);
assert(w.get_allocator() == a1);
```

The C++ standard *requires* that this does not assert. Assignment does not move the *allocator* of a container; that's how container assignment works with allocators in C++.

Therefore, either the allocator of the destination container can handle the memory of the source container, or it cannot. And if it cannot, then the destination container *must* allocate memory and copy/move the objects from the source.

Whether the move assignment operator is `noexcept` or not is a static property of the operator. And since PMRs cannot know until runtime whether they can propagate storage, the container must designate its move assignment operator as a throwing move assignment.

At runtime, it can actually decide whether propagation is possible or not. And if it is possible, then it will take the more efficient path.

Comment: @Nicol_Bolas I'm slightly confused by the sentence "Some polymorphic allocators can propagate to others, and some cannot." I mean polymorphic_allocator is just holding a pointer to a memory_resource to use for the allocation. My only guess is that this refers to the case when the memory resource used by the polymorphic_allocator is only intended to be used for allocation for a particular instance of say a std::pmr::vector? Is this correct?